# looping of functions with pauses

Tags: python, django, cron, celery, supervisord

There are two functions. Both should start when the server (`nginx`) starts and work throughout its life.

The `first function` should run every 5 minutes, the `second` - every 3 minutes (for example). It is possible that the function will run longer than the pause between its starts. It is necessary to start the pause counting from the moment the previous function ends.

If any of the functions breaks with an `error`, need to restart it.

How can this be implemented?

At the moment, this has been decided in a very crutch-like manner. Through while True in `celery` and `try / except` to check for a "break" function. It is clear that this needs to be rewritten.

So far, the thought comes to my mind with writing a management team with a `cron` and a `supervisor`. Or `celery beat`.

Comment: This is quite a broad question, but I always use celery beat for this kind of repeating tasks. Check out [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@yedjoe/celery-4-periodic-task-in-django-9f6b5a8c21c7) if you want to learn more about how to setup periodic tasks.

Comment: @NicoGriffioen Thank. Is it possible to implement using `celery beat`? `start the pause counting from the moment the previous function ends`

Comment: @NicoGriffioen I was added a new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58629790/how-can-to-run-task-in-5-minutes-after-finish-previous-task-using-celery-beat