# How can to run task in 5 minutes after finish previous task using celery-beat?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, task, celery

I have a two tasks - `a` and `b`.

Task `a` running in 5 minutes after finish previous task `a`.

Task `b` running in 3 minutes after finish previous task `b`.

How can I implement it? I'm use `python 3.6.8`, `Django 2.2.6` and `celery 4.3.0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't do this with celery beat because celery beat will trigger off of task start and not at task end.  If you absolutely need to do it three minutes after the previous task ends, you'd be advised to just adding a call to `.apply_async` at the end of both `a` and `b` and kicking off each task once.